# Is there any commonplace to run a code along with each test method I run in Java?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have collected a few java programs and I want to measure the memory that each program uses in the runtime at each test case. I have used Java `Runtime` to get the memory usage and that is fine.

My question is, is there any way to write a code(maybe a test method) to **run along with every test method** I run so that I don't have to copy and paste the code every time in order to calculate the memory usage for each test method individually. Is there any commonplace to run this code or else what would be the best approach for this problem?

If I give an example,
Let's say I have a Java program with five test cases and I want to calculate memory usage at each run of each test case! So, without having to copy and paste the code into each test case again and again to calculate the memory usage, can I implement something to run that memory calculating code **along with** each test case separately?

Any answer would be awesome!!!

Comment: have u try @BeforeEach

Comment: No, but I want to run the code inside each test method in order to get the memory usage of that particular test run!

Answer (score 0):

JUnit does provide annotations to run before and after running tests like [Before Each](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeEach.html) and [After Each](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/AfterEach.html). 
These annotations are used on those methods which must be run before & after each test method and in your case it an be used to print the Java memory usage

Comment: But I want to run the code inside each test method in order to get the memory usage of that particular test run! Not after or before, it needs to be run along with the test method or case!!

Comment: I did not quite get it. Do you want to check the memory usage at each step inside the test method OR you want to test the memory usage just before start and end of the test method?

Comment: Measuring memory is not quite really the problem here!!! My question is, how can I implement the code for measuring memory in a place where it runs along with every test method? For example, say I have placed my code in a java class and I have five test methods. So, when I run those five methods together, the code for measuring memory should run five times along with those five test methods!! Is that possible?

Comment: Thats exactly what the lifecylce methods are made for. Please go and read the documentation about the junit lifecycle. Or just try it.